# Oracle json object last value not in quotes

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

Take this as an example:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'a' value 'blah',
    'b' value 'blah',
    'c' value 'blah'
    FORMAT JSON)
FROM dual
```

The output is:

```
{"a":"blah","b":"blah","c":blah}
```

The last blah is not in quotes.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Am using:

```
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.17.0.0.0
```

**EDIT:**

To add to the mystery:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'a' value 1,
    'b' value 2,
    'c' value 'blah'
    FORMAT JSON)
FROM dual
```

gives me:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":blah}
```

but:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'a' value 1,
    'b' value 2,
    'c' value 3
    FORMAT JSON)
FROM dual
```

gives me:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT json_object(
    'a' value 1,
    'b' value 2,
    'c' value 3
    FORMAT JSON)
FROM dual
Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 15
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: [Oracle 18.4 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SPOiRKCr) [Oracle 21.3 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WCzF3M59)

Comment: cheers for this MT0.  It seems its the same in 18c and 21c also.  I guess this is a bug which has remained outstanding for some while, which makes it useless.  Will have to make my own functionality.

Comment: No, it is not a bug. It is intended behaviour (see my answer below) because you are telling Oracle (by using the `FORMAT JSON` keywords) that the input values are already valid JSON and it does not need to format them. If you want Oracle to format the strings (with surrounding quotes and escaping other quotes) then do not use the `FORMAT JSON` keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`JSON_OBJECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370):

> #### format_clause
>
> Specify `FORMAT JSON` after an input expression to declare that the value that results from it represents JSON data, and will therefore not be quoted in the output.

When you use `FORMAT JSON` then Oracle expects the value supplied to be valid JSON and will output the supplied value without applying any formatting to it. Therefore, if it is a string literal then you are expected to supply the surrounding quotes as part of the input value so that it is valid JSON when you use the `FORMAT JSON` option.

```sql
SELECT json_object(
         'a' value 'blah' FORMAT JSON,
         'b' value 'blah' FORMAT JSON,
         'c' value 'blah' FORMAT JSON
       ) AS formatted_values
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

| FORMATTED_VALUES |
| --- |
| {"a":blah,"b":blah,"c":blah} |

and:

```
SELECT json_object(
         'a' value 'blah',
         'b' value 'blah',
         'c' value 'blah' FORMAT JSON
       ) AS formatted_values
FROM   DUAL
```

outputs:

| FORMATTED_VALUES |
| --- |
| {"a":"blah","b":"blah","c":blah} |

If you want Oracle to quote the strings then do not use `FORMAT JSON`:

```sql
SELECT json_object(
         'a' value 'blah',
         'b' value 'blah',
         'c' value 'blah'
       ) AS formatted_values
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

| FORMATTED_VALUES |
| --- |
| {"a":"blah","b":"blah","c":"blah"} |

---

If you do want to use `FORMAT JSON` then make sure that the output values are valid JSON by providing the quotes:

```
SELECT json_object(
         'a' value '"blah"' FORMAT JSON,
         'b' value '"blah"' FORMAT JSON,
         'c' value '"blah"' FORMAT JSON
       ) AS formatted_values
FROM   DUAL
```

| FORMATTED_VALUES |
| --- |
| {"a":"blah","b":"blah","c":"blah"} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Ck8VSx_)

---

This behaviour is also mentioned in the [documentation for the `STRICT` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_OBJECT.html#GUID-1EF347AE-7FDA-4B41-AFE0-DD5A49E8B370):

> #### `STRICT`
>
> Specify the `STRICT` clause to verify that the output of the JSON generation function is correct JSON. If the check fails, a syntax error is raised.
>
> ##### Example 2: No quotes around output string when `FORMAT JSON` is used.
>
> ```
> SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('name' value 'Foo' FORMAT JSON ) FROM DUAL
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> | JSON_OBJECT('NAME'VALUE'FOO'FORMATJSON) |
> | --- |
> | {"name":Foo} |

Comment: And there was me thinkning the FORMAT JSON applied to the whole object and to it's desired output format.  This also solves the true false values issue that I was trying to solve - cheers for this MT0.